# IIS7 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have a website that I get the below error on whenever I navigate beyond the default.aspx page.

My issue is that when I run in debug mode via VS08 I do not get the error and when I run the code on a Webserver running IIS6 I do not get the error.  However, when I run my site on my development box against IIS7 I get the below error.  Also, I am running my IIS7 site out of C:\inetpub\wwwroot.  So I don't know how I could get the error in my C:\Users\ folder.  Finally, the method get_profile() has not existed in my code for over 2 weeks.

I have tried rebuilding the solution after deleting my .dlls, I have cleared IIS7s app pool, restarted it, restarted my computer, and redropped the entire folder contents from my development folder 5 times.  Nothing has fixed this error. What do I need to do?

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UserSession.get_profile() in C:\Users\<LocalUser>\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Website\Website\App_Code\UserSession.cs:20
   UserSession.Log() in C:\Users\<LocalUser>\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Website\Website\App_Code\UserSession.cs:83
   Website.MasterPages.Master.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\<LocalUser>\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Website\Website\MasterPages\Master.Master.cs:23
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing out the temp files.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30128\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

And rebuilding.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.  I even replaced all of the files in my IIS7 website directory.